# Entity object created with unique ID set to NULL in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a User entity class, on which I used `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities` the usual way. This class has a unique ID
among its variables :

```
class User 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    (...)
```

Much to my surprise, when I call `$user=new User();` in my code, the newly created object has its `$id` set to `NULL`. Given the annotations I gave, isn't Doctrine supposed to set it automatically ?

Sure, I am aware that I can add a `setId` method to my class, but I feel this is not the correct way to do things. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: As @ArturVesker said it won't be there until after you flush, in the same way that you don't know the ID of a row when doing regular `INSERT`. Another option is to generate your id yourself in your `__construct()` using a `UUID` (either passed in as an argument or like `$this->id = Uuid::uuid4()->toString()`) and change the strategy to `none`, this way your entity will always be valid (have an ID) as opposed to after flushing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique id will be set on `$em->flush($user)`. i.e after inserting in table.

You can get more information in [doctrine's documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-entities).

Comment: Link is 404. Why Doctrine didn't put redirects in I don't know